# System won't sleep, Kernel issue?

Tags: kernel, suspend, sleep

Randomly, my system will not enter s3 sleep properly, and thus does not wake up from sleep. I have noticed that when it does not enter s3 sleep correctly, entries in my journalctl from the kernel process are missing

Here is an output of journalctl from a successful sleep and wake cycle
https://pastebin.com/3MrgHjkS

And here is an unsuccessful one
https://pastebin.com/E1DRMYZv

Here is my inixi -F

```
111System:
  Host: DiamondArchPC Kernel: 6.5.6-arch2-1 arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 44.5 Distro: Arch Linux
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING v: Rev 1.xx
    serial: <superuser required> BIOS: American Megatrends v: 5302
    date: 10/20/2023
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache: L2: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2439 min/max: 2200/3700 cores: 1: 2200 2: 2200 3: 2200
    4: 2200 5: 2200 6: 2086 7: 2200 8: 4174 9: 2200 10: 2200 11: 2200 12: 2196
    13: 2200 14: 2200 15: 2200 16: 4175
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 22 [Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT/6750 XT / 6800M/6850M XT]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2.1 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: amdgpu unloaded: modesetting
    dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1: 2560x1440~165Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: radeonsi,swrast
    platforms: wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: amd mesa v: 23.2.1-arch1.2
    renderer: AMD Radeon RX 6750 XT (navi22 LLVM 16.0.6 DRM 3.54 6.5.6-arch2-1)
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 21/23 HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.6-arch2-1 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.84 status: active
Network:
  Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network driver: igb
  IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: 3c:7c:3f:21:96:ca
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlp8s0 state: up mac: 8c:c6:81:3b:04:8e
  IF-ID-1: virbr0 state: down mac: 52:54:00:ba:ec:06
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface driver: btusb type: USB
  Report: btmgmt ID: hci0 state: up address: 8C:C6:81:3B:04:92 bt-v: 4.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.07 TiB used: 886.83 GiB (41.9%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 970 EVO 1TB size: 931.51 GiB
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: BC511 NVMe 256GB
    size: 238.47 GiB
  ID-3: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-08WN4A0
    size: 931.51 GiB
  ID-4: /dev/sdb vendor: Verbatim model: STORE N GO size: 14.45 GiB
    type: USB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 902.81 GiB used: 814.63 GiB (90.2%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p4
  ID-2: /boot size: 512 MiB used: 252.5 MiB (49.3%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 12.71 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%)
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0 C mobo: 37.0 C gpu: amdgpu temp: 56.0 C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): cpu: 1008 case-1: 998 case-2: 0 case-3: 982 gpu: amdgpu
    fan: 0
Info:
  Processes: 423 Uptime: 4m Memory: total: 32 GiB available: 31.26 GiB
  used: 3.24 GiB (10.4%) Shell: fish inxi: 3.3.30
```

Comment: Checking whether you have the latest BIOS/UEFI firmware installed is always a good idea for this kind of issues. Also describe your environment a bit better (which Linux exactly?).